# How to add gradient color to Jbuttons placed in jtoolbar

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, jtoolbar

I am using netbeans platform module to develop this desktop application. I am using drag and drop facility in netbeans in the developement.

I needed to create a toolbar which is having few buttons..I need to create a gradient color for these buttons.

I dragged and dropped `JToolBar`,  over it I dragged and placed `JButton` objects.
In the properties of the button I have selected a color for which I want a shaded color. In the custom code I have modified.

```
jbutton = new javax.swing.Jbutton();
```

as below

```
jbutton = new javax.swing.JButton(){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
           RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
            getBackground().brighter().brighter().brighter(), 0, getHeight(),
            getBackground().darker());
         g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(grphcs);
    }};
```

When I used the above code for a `JPanel` in my project it worked but it is not showing any effect when I used it for a button.

How to get a gradient color for a button placed in a toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button has a `contentAreaFilled` attribute which determines if the look and feel should paint the content area of the button.  When you call `super.paintComponent`, the look and feel delegate will paint over what you have done.

You can set this property to `false` and it should then work.

For example...

[image: RoundButton]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GradientButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GradientButtons();
    }

    public GradientButtons() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new RoundButton("Click me"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RoundButton extends JButton {

        public RoundButton(String text) {
            super(text);
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            int radius = Math.max(size.width, size.height);
            size.width = radius;
            size.height = radius;
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                    Color.RED, 0, getHeight(),
                    Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }

}
```

You may want to check the `ButtonModel`'s `armed` and/or `pressed` state so you can also change the way that the button is painted when clicked, as a suggestion...