# remove default border from JButton

Tags: java, swing

Hi just a quick question. I want to remove the ugly grey border the JButtons create.

http://gyazo.com/e9f57308190e1b6d49ac7b300fce2a4b

```
    setBackground(null);
    .setOpaque(false);
    .setBorderPainted(false);
```

none of these work, im sure it's a one liner, any help appricated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a combination of `JButton#setContentAreaFilled` and `JButton#setBorderPainted`

You might also like to use `JButton#setFocusPainted` as well

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397792/how-to-fill-the-surface-of-the-jbutton-completely-with-an-imageicon/24398514#24398514), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113294/how-to-maintain-transparency-for-jbuttons-java/30113446#30113446) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358157/how-to-add-gradient-color-to-jbuttons-placed-in-jtoolbar/23358390#23358390)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can use the `setBorder()` method for this. Something along these lines should work:

```
Border noBorder = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 0);
JButton borderlessButton = new JButton("No Border");
borderlessButton.setBorder(noBorder);
```